# Apollo SM RCS specific impulse?

Tags: rockets, apollo-program, propulsion, specific-impulse, rcs

What is the specific impulse of the RCS thrusters on the Apollo Service Module? [This document](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM10_Reaction_Control_ppRC1-12.pdf) cites 281 seconds for the LM's RCS thrusters, but I cannot find similar specs for the SM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some resources ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-4D), [Astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/r/r-4d.html)) give 312 seconds for the R-4D, but I think that's for the large-nozzle modern version.

Marquardt's ["Apollo SM-LM RCS Engine Development Program Summary Report"](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19690029234.pdf) gives the nominal specific impulse as 280 seconds, and gives figures for flown engines on Lunar Orbiter I-V as 276.1 to 279.5 seconds. The Lunar Orbiters, the Apollo LM, and the Apollo SM all used the R-4D. The exact specific impulse will vary with mixture ratio and tank pressurization, so I don't think the 276-281 second range is particularly significant.

Comment: I also found information in the [CSM/LM Operational Data Book Part 1 Constraints and Performance](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/HSI-41539.pdf), Table 4.3-1 onwards